# How to save the output of pyttsx3 to a temporary file?

Tags: python-3.x, text-to-speech, temporary-files, pyttsx3

I am able to store the TTS output to a file using the following code

```py
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

engine.save_to_file('Hello World!', 'hello.mp3')
engine.runAndWait()
```

Is it is possible to store this to a temporary file instead for an Api service I am creating.

I did some digging around the pyttsx3 source code and found [this](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/blob/5d3755b060a980f48fcaf81df018dd06cbd17a8f/pyttsx3/driver.py#L153-L162)

```py
    def save_to_file(self, text, filename, name):
        '''
        Called by the engine to push a say command onto the queue.
        @param text: Text to speak
        @type text: unicode
        @param name: Name to associate with the utterance
        @type name: str
        '''
        self._push(self._driver.save_to_file, (text, filename), name)
```

Which invokes the following [code](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/blob/5d3755b060a980f48fcaf81df018dd06cbd17a8f/pyttsx3/drivers/sapi5.py#L65-L74)

```py
 def save_to_file(self, text, filename):
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        stream = comtypes.client.CreateObject('SAPI.SPFileStream')
        stream.Open(filename, SpeechLib.SSFMCreateForWrite)
        temp_stream = self._tts.AudioOutputStream
        self._tts.AudioOutputStream = stream
        self._tts.Speak(fromUtf8(toUtf8(text)))
        self._tts.AudioOutputStream = temp_stream
        stream.close()
        os.chdir(cwd)
```

However I am not able to quite understand how to implement what I have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to [@Jiangshan00001](https://github.com/Jiangshan00001/pyttsx4)

By making [changes](https://github.com/Jiangshan00001/pyttsx4/blob/master/pyttsx4/drivers/sapi5.py#L70-L73) to the sapi5 driver script you can pass a BytesIO object instead of filename.

```py
import pyttsx4
from io import BytesIO

engine = pyttsx4.init()
b = BytesIO()
engine.save_to_file('Hello World!', b)
engine.runAndWait()
```